# Display Age from date of birth

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I need help with displaying an age when I enter a date of birth. I have tried this JS method but I cannot get it to display.

```html
<div class="kidsFormCenter">
               
                    {% for kid in kids %}
                    <table class="kidsTable kidForm">
                        <form action="{% url 'update_profile_kid' kid.id %}" method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>First name:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" value="{{ kid.name }}" name="name"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Date of Birth:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" maxlength="10" value="{{ kid.dob }}" name="dob"></td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="age" class="form-control" required readonly></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gender:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" maxlength="1" value="{{ kid.gender }}" name="gender"></td>
                                
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-primary" formaction="{% url 'update_profile_kid' kid.id %}" type="submit">Edit</button>
                                    <form action="{% url 'delete_profile_kid' kid.id %}" method="POST">
                                        {% csrf_token %}<button class="btn btn-info" formaction="{% url 'delete_profile_kid' kid.id %}" type="submit">Delete</button></td>
                                    </form>        
                            </tr>
                        </form>
                    </table>
                    <br>

            {% endfor %}
            
            </div>
```

And my age.js is

```html
$(function() {
    $('input[name="dob"]').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        showDropdowns: true
    }, 
    function(start, end, label) {
        var years = moment().diff(start, 'years');
        $("#age").val("You are " + years + " years old.");
    });
});
```

I want the age of the child to be displayed.[image]

Comment: is your callback function being fired?  Are you receiving errors in the console?

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition

Comment: No, I am not receiving any errors. It appears as blank when i inspect it in chrome.